# Yii - sorting only actually displayed GridView without connecting to mysql

Tags: jquery, sorting, gridview, yii

I would like to have a gridview where I could sort actaully displayed values. I don't wan't to get different data from database but simply sort the displayed one. Just like jquery tablesorter plugin. Is is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can populate an array, and create a CArrayDataProvider. This will create a sortable result set that is not linked to the database. You do not need to use models, you can use any data source you wish.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider

Comment: I am actually trying to do it with CArrayDataProvider but it's not working. It still uses ajax to do the sorting.